# How to grind smooth hard rock to create a road surface

Tags: masonry

I have a situation where I have a rough granite roadway about 15 feet wide and 50 feet long. The granite is solid granite. The surface variability is on the order of a maximum of about 4 inches. In other words at no place on the surface is one segment of the granite more than 4 inches higher than the granite adjacent.

I need to smooth this into a crown. A crown is a gentle slope that allows water to shed off to the side of the road.

Is there any kind of mechanized equipment that can do this kind of work?

Comment: Wasn't that the type of reason they invented dynamite... much faster than a gang with hammers and chisels or picks and shovels...

Comment: Is it crushed granite or not.  I am having trouble envisioning a solid granite driveway.

Comment: @paparazzo, this may help you envision: [Half Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_Dome) is a single chunk of granite.

Comment: I know half dome is a singe piece of granite.  It still does not answer if your driveway is a single piece of granite.

Answer (score 2):

Granite is hard a rock. On the [Mohs scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness) of hardness, which rates talc (being soft) at 1 and diamond (being the hardest material) at 10, granite is rated at being [6 to 7](https://www.reference.com/science/hard-granite-mohs-hardness-scale-f6ecbd0cce3a459a).

The old way to do what you want to achieve is to drill and blast the area of interest to create a trench deeper than you require. This would then be back filled with finer grained fill to produce the smooth profiled surface you require.

Regarding rock grinding, some companies offer [rock grinding services](http://hardrockgrinding.com/). The pictures this company provides on its website show soft material being ground. The picks on the grinding drum/head are large and are spaced far apart. What you need is a grinding drum with the picks closer together.

It a case of getting the correct gear for the application, if it is available and whether it is affordable.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect he's looking at hundreds of dollars US per foot of driveway at a minimum.

Comment: It looks like the rock grinding service company linked to could to the job but it would be a lot easier and cheaper to pave over with asphalt.  That would not have the character or be as much fun as grinding the granite but it won't break the bank, either.